# remote debugging emacs 24 and gdb

Tags: emacs, gdb, tramp

I have code on a compute node of a cluster.  I can't ssh directly to the compute node so I first set up an ssh tunnel with

```
ssh -f cluster.master.node -L 2222:cluster.compute.node:22 -N.
```

Next I visit the file with

<kbd>C-x C-f</kbd> /ssh:user@localhost#2222/path/to/blah.c.

Finally I do

<kbd>M-x</kbd> gdb.

In emacs 23 I would do

Run gdb (like this)  gdb --annotate=3/ssh:localhost#2222:/path/to/program

but documentation for the gdb function in emacs 24 says "The command-line
options should include -i=mi to use gdb's MI text interface.  Note that the old "--annotate" option is no longer supported."

Running

gdb (like this)  gdb --i=mi /ssh:loalhost#2222:/path/to/program

seems to work, but when I try to run the program I get "Starting program: /misc/home/joey/git/proteus/proteus /dev/pts/5: No such file or directory."  The problems seems to be with the non-existent /misc/ directory prepended to the path of the executable.  Even when I do a cd to /home/joey/git/proteus/ the response is "Working directory /home/joey/git/proteus (canonically /misc/home/joey/git/proteus)."

Can I remotely debug my program in Emacs 24 or should I go back to 23?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try M-x gud-gdb RET: it will give you the old Emacs-22 behavior.